# How to restart device motion after return from screen lock?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-motion

I found a problem in iOS 7 which occurs often but not always.

First I set up device motion like this:

```
[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical
                                                               toQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                                           withHandler:motionHandler];
```

It works until the user locks the screen on iPad Mini with iOS 7.
When the user waits about 5 seconds before he unlocks the screen again, device motion works fine again.

When the user unlocks the screen quickly after locking it, device motion stops working and the handler isn't called anymore.

I assume that in this case the programmer must restart device motion manually. What is the recommended way to guarantee that device motion is running successfully?

Answer (score 0):

try to override these methods from the AppDelegate

> -(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
>
> -(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
>
> -(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application

GL HF